# Can't take Laravel cookie that's been set

Tags: laravel, cookies

I have a checkbox in my login form and if it is checked I want to save user's email and password in a cookie so then he'll be automatically logged in. This is the part of my code that checks if the checkbox is checked and sets the cookie.

```
if ($remember == 'on') {

                    $array = array(

                        "email" => $email,
                        "password" => $password

                    );

                    $time = time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60);

                    Cookie::queue('user', serialize($array), $time);

                }
```

But when I try to get the cookie and print it out it prints "false".

```
$cookie = Cookie::get('user');

dd(unserialize($cookie));
```

How can I get the cookie? It shows the cookie that's been set in inspect. 
What's the best way to check if the cookie is set so i'll redirect the user to profile view straight away? Do I have to write a middleware for it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `dd` function call.

Cookies will store in user's browser when he retrieve the response with your Cookies attached (set-cookie headers), and you can read them in the next request that he will send to you.

when you call `dd`, it breaks the response chain and removes the `set-cookie` headers.

just remove the `dd` and in another route write:

```
dd(unserialize(\Request::cookie('user')));
```